# Postfix - disable open relay

Tags: postfix-mta, sasl

I set SASL up on my postfix server and ran an open relay test. The relay access was denied (which is what I want) in all cases except when the sender and recipient are both on my domain.

I'd like to force authentication in all cases except when the sender is localhost.

Did search trying to find out how to do that but couldn't find anything useful. I'd appreciate some help with this, thanks.

Comment: you would have more luck asking on superuser than stack overflow I would have thought